# Wrt speed, how optimised is QuantLib's Heston pricing class?

Tags: options, quantlib, optimization, heston

I have a pricing formula that is 300x the speed of the QuantLib's Heston pricing class. Is it incredibly slow?

For context, on a slow 1.6 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 processor, my method can reliably price 1000 different options in 0.005 seconds whilst it takes the QuantLib's 1.5 seconds.

And what method/integration are they using? I cannot find it on their documentation or in their code anywhere. It uses the C++ library if I understand correctly, and I know 0 C++

I am using cosine expansion, the method can be found [here](https://repositorio.ul.pt/bitstream/10451/24663/1/ulfc118677_tm_Carla_Baptista.pdf). But I am have made my own adjustments to truncate even more terms of the summation.

From the QL library, I have been using the code:

```
strikes = np.arange(50, 200, 0.01)
today = ql.Date(26, 10, 2023)
expiry_date = today + ql.Period(int(365*tau), ql.Days)

risk_free_curve = ql.FlatForward(today, r, ql.Actual365Fixed())
flat_curve = ql.FlatForward(today, 0.0, ql.Actual365Fixed())
riskfree_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(risk_free_curve)
dividend_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(flat_curve)

heston_process = ql.HestonProcess(riskfree_ts, dividend_ts, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(S0)), v0, kappa, theta, sigma, rho)
heston_model = ql.HestonModel(heston_process)

option = ql.EuropeanOption( ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(ql.Option.Call, strike), ql.EuropeanExercise(expiry_date))
heston_engine = ql.AnalyticHestonEngine(heston_model)
option.setPricingEngine(heston_engine)
option_price = option.NPV()
```

And then just using `time.time()` to test the speed.

Comment: What is your method? Code? Language? What quantlib code do you run? How did you benchmark?

Comment: @AKdemy I have made an update to the post

Comment: I generally consider QuantLib a weak library, but the integration routines are decent.  In order to judge algorithm performance, it is not enough to use calculation time.  You need to find the curves of computation accuracy (y axis) versus computation time (x axis) as you vary quadrature parameters.

Answer (score 4):

QuantLib does a lot of things behind the scenes that provide convenient functionality but get in the way of pure speed.  For instance, in your example code, when you write

```
risk_free_curve = ql.FlatForward(today, r, ql.Actual365Fixed())
```

you're building a whole term structure of interest rates, from which the pricing code will extract a zero rate in order to pass it to the Heston formula.  In your case, this is obviously wasteful; it will retrieve the same rate `r` that you passed.  And your code, instead, probably uses `r` directly and avoids all these calculations and function calls, and therefore is a lot faster.  But in a real world case, the risk-free curve would be (for instance) bootstrapped on a set of OIS swaps, and in this case QuantLib becomes more convenient because if you have a set of options, you can pass the curve and let the library extract the correct zero rate for each option based on its maturity.

The same goes for a number of other features: they are convenient for a number of common use cases of the library, but the added infrastructure means that the code has no hope to be as fast as a bare-bones implementation of the model.

One last thing: I'm not sure how you loop over the options, but if you have (as it seems from `strikes = np.arange(50, 200, 0.01)`) a set of options on the same underlying and with different strikes, you can instantiate the curves, the process, the model and the pricing engine just once and pass the same pricing engine to all the options.  I'm not sure if you're already doing this when you're timing QuantLib, of if you're recreating those objects each time.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. Yes, you are correct that I was looping with the QL library. In my code I was able to vectorise the summation and options, whilst the QL version was for looping so I wasn't comparing apples to apples. Although, it still is slower after updating it as you point out. v