# When is the Quantlib's C++ to python package faster than just coding natively in python?

Tags: quantlib

Every package I have used of the QL's python package thus far have been slower than my own local python functions. From what I understand, it's running C++ underneath, but if you are running loops/iterations in python, it will be doing the C++ operations separately and thus isn't well optimised. (I've never used C++ so I'm not sure when it's computationally efficient).

Does anyone have an example and types of situations when quantlib's python package will be faster than just running the code natively in python?

Comment: In theory it swig is light weight and should be very fast, I wonder if it's the default compiling options used and then how you are using it that slow things down e.g. python multithreading. Is

Comment: How is this question different from the one you asked [before](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/77181/54838). Obviously it's faster if you just code a simple function that does exactly one thing (take inputs and price it).